# How to write SQL for stock mutations based on daily stock reports

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am feeding my database (Microsoft SQL server) with daily stock reports and I want to report the daily outgoing products/quantities with SQL. Every incoming shipment gets an inboundID, these are also known by each product.
With outgoing quantities I mean 2 things:

- if the quantity of 1 product of the same inboundID decreases the next day
- if a known inboundID (seen before) disappears from the stock report, the last known stock of this inboundID reports the outbound quantity

Can I get outbound reports based on this with SQL querie(s)?

Hereby the sample stock reports:

```
+-------------+------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| ArticleCode |         Description          | InboundID | TotalStock |   Date    |
+-------------+------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| BAM131-L    | Jacket in piqu? Georgia L    |  53800222 |        550 | yesterday |
| BAM131-XXXL | Jacket in piqu? Georgia XXXL |  53800220 |      18000 | yesterday |
| BAM133-XXXL | Shirt piqu? Dave XXXL        |  53800220 |      18000 | yesterday |
| BAM133-XL   | Shirt piqu? Dave XL          |  53800222 |          1 | yesterday |
| BAM133-XXL  | Shirt piqu? Dave XXL         |  53800215 |       1800 | yesterday |
| BAM133-S    | Shirt piqu? Dave S           |  53800215 |        787 | yesterday |
| BAM133-M    | Shirt piqu? Dave M           |  53800215 |         59 | yesterday |
| BAM133-L    | Shirt piqu? Dave L           |  53800218 |         50 | yesterday |
| BAM134-XXL  | Shirt Piqu? Lop XXL          |  53800215 |        700 | yesterday |
| BAM134-L    | Shirt Piqu? Lop L            |  53800218 |        300 | yesterday |
| BAM134-S    | Shirt Piqu? Lop S            |  53800218 |        750 | yesterday |
| BAM134-XL   | Shirt Piqu? Lop XL           |  53800218 |          5 | yesterday |
| BAM134-XS   | Shirt Piqu? Lop XS           |  53800215 |         89 | yesterday |
| BAM135-XL   | Coat Leather Jumper XL       |  53800218 |          1 | yesterday |
| BAM135-L    | Coat Leather Jumper L        |  53800300 |          2 | yesterday |
| BAM135-XXXL | Coat Leather Jumper XXXL     |  53800215 |         60 | yesterday |
| BAM135-XXL  | Coat Leather Jumper XXL      |  53800218 |        297 | yesterday |
+-------------+------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+

+-------------+------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| ArticleCode |         Description          | InboundID | TotalStock |   Date    |
+-------------+------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| BAM131-L    | Jacket in piqu? Georgia L    |  53800222 |        500 | today|
| BAM131-XXXL | Jacket in piqu? Georgia XXXL |  53800220 |      18000 | today|
| BAM133-XXXL | Shirt piqu? Dave XXXL        |  53800220 |      18000 | today|
| BAM133-XL   | Shirt piqu? Dave XL          |  53800222 |          1 | today|
| BAM133-XXL  | Shirt piqu? Dave XXL         |  53800215 |       1800 | today|
| BAM133-S    | Shirt piqu? Dave S           |  53800215 |        787 | today|
| BAM133-M    | Shirt piqu? Dave M           |  53800215 |         59 | today|
| BAM133-L    | Shirt piqu? Dave L           |  53800218 |         50 | today|
| BAM134-XXL  | Shirt Piqu? Lop XXL          |  53800215 |        700 | today|
| BAM134-L    | Shirt Piqu? Lop L            |  53800218 |        300 | today|
| BAM134-S    | Shirt Piqu? Lop S            |  53800218 |        750 | today|
| BAM134-XL   | Shirt Piqu? Lop XL           |  53800218 |          5 | today|
    | BAM134-XS   | Shirt Piqu? Lop XS           |  53800215 |         89 | today|
    | BAM135-XL   | Coat Leather Jumper XL       |  53800218 |          1 | today|
 today|
    | BAM135-XXXL | Coat Leather Jumper XXXL     |  53800215 |         60 | today|
    | BAM135-XXL  | Coat Leather Jumper XXL      |  53800218 |        297 | today|
    +-------------+------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Desired result:

```
        +-------------+------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
        | ArticleCode |         Description          | InboundID | Gone       |   Date    |
        +-------------+------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
        | BAM131-L    | Jacket in piqu? Georgia L    |  53800222 |          50|      today|
        | BAM131-XXXL | Coat Leather Jumper L        |  53800300 |           2|      today|
        +-------------+------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: OK you provided the first part that Gordon asked for. How about sample data and desired results? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: thanks for your advice, first time I am posting here so please apologize for my mistakes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Y.ArticleCode, Y.Description, Y.InboundId, (Y.TotalStock - ISNULL(T.TotalStock,0)) Gone, T.Date
From Yesterday Y
Left Join Today T
On Y.ArticleCode = T.ArticleCode
And Y.InboundID = T.InboundID
```